# Laravel 8 - Trait boot not firing

Tags: laravel, media-library

I am using [Spatie Media Library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/introduction) in my project. I have added columns to the `media` table for user ids to track who uploaded or updated and image (images have metadata associated with them). But the boot method in the `media class` is not firing.

My `media` class is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media as BaseMedia;

class Media extends BaseMedia
{
    /**
     * Table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'media';

    /**
     * Append
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['url', 'ext'];

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        /**
         * Creating the record
         */
        static::creating(function ($obj) {

            $user = auth()->user();

            if (! $user) {
                if (! $obj->creator_id) {
                    $obj->creator_id = 1;
                    $obj->updater_id = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $obj->creator_id = $user->id;
                $obj->updater_id = $user->id;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Updating the record
         */
        static::updating(function ($obj) {

            $user = auth()->user();

            if (! $user) {
                $obj->updater_id = 1;
            } else {
                $obj->updater_id = $user->id;
            }

        });

       /**
        * Global scope to retrieve creator and updater
        */
        static::addGlobalScope('CreatorUpdater', function (Builder $builder) 
        {
            $builder->with('creator', 'updater');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Get Url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getFullUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Get Ext
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getExtAttribute()
    {
        $arr = explode('.', $this->file_name);

        return $arr[count($arr) - 1];
    }

    /**
     * Creator
     */
    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'creator_id');
    }

    /**
     * Updater
     */
    public function updater()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'updater_id');
    }
}
```

What have I missed? If I `Log` in the `boot` method I get no log entries.

Answer (score 0):

Argh! I just needed to point the media library to my model and not Spatie's.

In the `media-library.php` config file:

```
/*
 * The fully qualified class name of the media model.
 */
'media_model' => App\Models\Media::class,
```